# Mongoid: retrieving documents whose _id exists in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-ruby

I am trying to fetch the documents from a collection based on the existence of a reference to these documents in another collection.

Let's say I have two collections `Users` and `Courses` and the models look like this:

- User: `{_id, name}`
- Course: `{_id, name, user_id}`

Note: this just a hypothetical example and not actual use case. So let's assume that duplicates are fine in the name field of `Course`. Let's thin `Course as CourseRegistrations`.

Here, I am maintaining a reference to `User` in the `Course` with the `user_id` holding the `_Id` of `User`. And note that its stored as a string.

Now I want to retrieve all users who are registered to a particular set of courses.

I know that it can be done with two queries. That is first run a query and get the `users_id` field from the `Course` collection for the set of courses. Then query the `User` collection by using `$in` and the user ids retrieved in the previous query. But this may not be good if the number of documents are in tens of thousands or more.

Is there a better way to do this in just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying is a typical `sql join`. But thats not possible in mongodb. As you suggested already you can do that in 2 different queries.

There is one more way to handle it. Its not exactly a solution, but the valid workaround in NonSql databases. That is to store most frequently accessed fields inside the same collection.

You can store the some of the `user` collection fields, inside the `course` collection as embedded  field.

```
Course : {
   _id : 'xx',
   name: 'yy'
   user:{
       fname : 'r',
       lname :'v',
       pic: 's'
   }  
}
```

This is a good approach if the subset of fields you intend to retrieve from user collection is less. You might be wondering the redundant user data stored in `course` collection, but that's exactly what makes mongodb powerful. Its a one time insert but your queries will be lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Extending the question a bit. Lets say I want to use pagination as well. The two query approach will not work isnt it? I cannot retrieve pages of users who are registered to a particular set of courses. Your alternative solution could work with pagination as well.